# Why do "non-stand-alone" artifacts exist?

Tags: java, wiremock, artifact

I started to learn WireMock. My first experience is not very positive. Here's a failing MRE:

```java
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class GenericTest {
    @Test
    void test() {
        new WireMockServer(8090);
    }
}
```

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wiremock</groupId>
            <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/thread/ThreadPool
```

I debugged it a little:

```java
  public WireMockServer(int port) {
    this(/* -> this */ wireMockConfig() /* <- throws */.port(port));
  }
```

```java
// WireMockConfiguration

  // ↓ throwing inline
  private ThreadPoolFactory threadPoolFactory = new QueuedThreadPoolFactory();

  public static WireMockConfiguration wireMockConfig() {
    return /* implicit no-args constructor */ new WireMockConfiguration();
  }
```

```java
package com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.jetty;

import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.Options;
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.ThreadPoolFactory;
// ↓ package org.eclipse does not exist, these lines are in red
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ThreadPool;

public class QueuedThreadPoolFactory implements ThreadPoolFactory {

  @Override
  public ThreadPool buildThreadPool(Options options) {
    return new QueuedThreadPool(options.containerThreads());
  }
}
```

My conclusions:

1. WireMock has a dependency on `org.eclipse`
2. WireMock doesn't include this dependency in its artifact
3. I have to provide it manually

```xml
<!-- like so -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
    <version>12.0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

I even visited their [GitHub](https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock/tree/master) to see for myself if the dependency is marked as `provided`, but they use Gradle, and I don't know Gradle

But that's not all! You'll also have to include (at least) `com.github.jknack.handlebars` and `com.google.common.cache` (see `com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.extension.responsetemplating.TemplateEngine`)

Luckily, I found this "stand-alone" artifact that doesn't require any manual props

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wiremock</groupId>
            <artifactId>wiremock-standalone</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

My question:
Why aren't all artifacts "stand-alone"? Why do artifacts that don't work unless propped up by manually declared dependencies even exist, what are their advantages?

Comment: I hope it's not subjective. If it should be rephrased to be on topic, I'm all for it

Comment: A standalone artifact vendors its dependencies, copying them into its own jars. That makes a horrible mess whenever you need to use more than one thing distributed that way and their dependency chains overlap, and it greatly complicates security updates of transitive dependencies.

Comment: Note that just declaring a dependency so your toolchain (Maven, etc) can automatically resolve it and download the things it needs does _not_ make something standalone. Software following best practices doesn't need things to be standalone to avoid manual work when you're correctly using dependency management tools.

Comment: Mind, there are two separate questions here and it's not clear which one you meant to ask. One is about wiremock specifically and why your use of it didn't pull in jetty-util automatically -- that might be a bug in wiremock's packaging, I'd have to investigate. The other is why people don't use standalone jars everywhere, and that's a **very** different question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy do you mean there could be problems if one library pulls, for example, one `jetty-util` version, and another another version?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I didn't ask the former question in the post's current edition

Comment: Shame; the former question (that you didn't ask) is fact-intensive and answerable without getting into weighing competing values against each other. And yes, I _absolutely_ mean it makes problems when you're using multiple standalone libraries and they have conflicting dependency versions. It also makes problems when you're trying to use library X directly, which bundles in a version of library Y with a security bug that's been fixed (but where the fix isn't yet bundled into the version embedded in the latest published version of X).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy as far as I know, questions like "what are advantages of X" are on-topic on StackOverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In Normal Operation, Maven Calculates and Downloads Transitive Dependencies

There's a presumption in the question that it was *normal and expected* by Wiremock's development team that you would manually add jetty-util as an explicit dependency when not using the standalone artifact. That's not true: *This was a bug.*

The alternative to standalone jars is not needing to add dependencies yourself. The alternative to standalone JARs is having the POM for a project specify compatibility constraints on all its dependencies, so that Maven can combine all the constraints of all the dependencies and try to calculate a dependency set that satisfies all those constraints.

---

#### Vendoring Dependencies Sets Up Conflicts

<sub>(A quick terminology note: To "vendor" a dependency is to redistribute it yourself; this is what "standalone" JARs do).</sub>

Let's say that you're using library A, which requires C version 1.2.3 or newer (but not past 1.4.99); and library B, which requires C version 1.3.0 or newer (but not 2.0+).

When Maven is calculating a dependency set, this is easy: it knows that the overall project requires a version of C that's at least 1.3.0, and not 1.5+. It thus might pick, say, 1.4.15.

By contrast, if library A bundled in C==1.2.3 to a standalone jar, *that version of C is on the overall project's classpath*, so library B can end up getting C 1.2.3 even though it doesn't work with any version of C older than 1.3.0.

There are mechanisms like [OSGi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi) to automate setup of multiple classloaders with different dependency chains active within the same JVM at the same time to allow concurrent use of conflicting library versions, but these add a great deal of complexity on their own -- it's very much best avoided.

---

### Versioning Dependencies Prevents Security Updates

You're using Library A in standalone mode, which *vendors* C 1.2.3.

There's a major vulnerability discovered in C releases older than 1.4.13. Now what?

If you weren't operating in standalone mode, Maven could resolve to the newest available version that was compatible with everything in your dependency chain; but because you're letting your dependencies pull in versions of transitive dependencies *they* packaged at build time, now you need to wait until library A publishes a new release.

If they only publish that new release on a branch you aren't compatible with -- too bad, so sad, nothing you can do about it without a bunch of build engineering work to pull content out of the jar they distributed at build time.

Answer (score 1):

You were getting the exception because the `3.5.0` and `3.5.1` releases of WireMock had an issue with the POM, meaning that Maven wouldn’t fully download transitive dependencies. `3.5.2` fixes this.

I would try upgrading to `3.5.2` and running your original code again.

The release of `3.5.2` can be found here - https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock/releases/tag/3.5.2

Comment: This is a good answer to the question the OP should have asked -- but if you go through comments on the question, they [directly state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78247870/why-do-non-stand-alone-artifacts-exist?noredirect=1#comment137949215_78247870) that they _aren't_ asking about why Maven wasn't downloading transitive dependencies for wiremock, and that the question is limited to why people don't categorically vendor dependencies into a standalone jar in the first place.